# Coreaudio render callback in monotouch

Tags: xamarin.ios, core-audio

Ok --- am I soooo close to releasing my audio analysis application and I found an issue with monotouch using core audio. Monotouch actually has binding for core audio / remote io and a sample written was by Miguel that works nicely. That works great 99% of the time. The problem arrises where I think the "stop the world" garbage collector occurs during a render callback in coreaudio. At that point we are in managed code so I can thinking that the render callback is not going to return until the gc is finished. As a result, about 1 out of every 160 frames is dropped (approx every 2 to 4 seconds).

So I have three options without the wisdom to know which is a waste of time.

Write the code audio render callback (and all the other core audio interface code) in c. Then I could pinvoke to get the samples as fast as my managed code can analyze it. This would avoid dropped frames even if I get paused for 20 ms. My main question is can I do this with monotouch? Will the core audio callback function get stopped by the gc if it is completely unmanaged? I could then have an unmanaged circular queue that I pinvoke to read data as necessary.

Just tune the gc in some way to be less efficient but with less time of the world paused. If it was always under 5 ms we would probably be safe. I don't know how to do this in xamarin studio. Is it just a bunch of linker options or something?

Use another API. I've tried the input queue API but the latency was terrible. Is there a middle ground?

I know CoreAudio is awesome and all that, but have to admit the Android port of this app was about 100x faster in this area to develop for my needs.

Comment: if you have a reproducible test case I would submit it as a bug to Xamarin and see what they say

Comment: Sure I could do that---I don't think this is exactly a bug per say, more that it is "working as designed": the render callback expects a certain time guarantee and the gc can take that away.  It still would be good for me to pass it along considering there have to be more people who want low-latency audio recording in monotouch without glitches.

Comment: if it can be done in Obj-C, you should be able to do it with MT, and I think Xamarin would agree.  If the GC is somehow interfering, either the GC needs to be tuned, or possibly there is a different approach you could take in your code.  Either way, I think the Xamarin guys would like to see your code to see where the conflict might be.

Comment: ok-I did figure out that I was being way to aggressive on the preferredhardwareIOBufferDuration = 0.005.  That's 5 ms which even changing it to 0.010 makes my problem go away.  I'll look into the profiler to see how long my gc pauses are.  Of course on older hardware (I am developing on a 5th gen ipod touch), things will be slower.

Comment: I would like to look at your app, to see where the GC is impacting you and provide some feedback.  Can you share it with us at Xamarin?   File a bug report and flag it as "private" to keep your contents private.

Comment: Thanks Miguel: added as Bug 13982: Dropped frames in CoreAudio render callback

Answer (score 4):

Apple DTS recommends not even using generic Objective C methods in short duration Core Audio callbacks, only deterministic straight C (maybe static dispatch C++).  Any dynamic dispatch or memory management can potentially cause audio underflow.  So unless you can turn off, or guaranteed deterministically bound, all GC and other memory management inside the Monotouch runtime (doubtful) it's probably not appropriate for real-time callbacks.

That's the cost of low latency audio, especially on older hardware.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.  Fontunately my application can handle dropping one frame out of every million.  Just not one out of every 160 or so.  Increasing the minumum response time from 5ms to 20ms gives the gc plenty of room to get its job done.  I am still wondering if I did go down the "write it all in a native library" if the monotouch runtime could still stop the core audio callback, or since it is completely unmanaged if I can do it there.

Comment: Also note that iOS can change the buffer duration from that requested by an app after an audio unit has been started.  If there is zero blocking and managed code in the real-time audio thread, it seems unlikely that other runtime code could effect that thread much.

Comment: Very true, so I might not be able to get away with setting the hardware buffer size myself.  Looks like the best way to guarantee the samples is to write the interface and callback completely in native code and use a lock free circular queue or something (basically option 1 from above).  Not sure if this is overkill or high quality engineering.

Comment: Low latency audio requires a certain minimum quality of engineering.  Getting things working reliably is certainly not overkill.  Using lock free circular buffers/queues is a very common solution to getting data in/out of real-time audio.